# Take pictures without saving to the phone

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an ios application where the user can take an image using his phone camera and send it via email without saving it in the phone (for confidentiality reaons).
I searched in google but i couldnt find anything helpful.
is this possible ? if no, is there any work arounds ?

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` with camera source won't save picture you have taken. have you tried it?

Comment: @kathayatnk it does save but it is saved to a temporary location

Comment: Just mail the picker controller temporary image url and you are good to go.

Comment: yeah, it should get deleted from temp location. What's causing the problem?

Comment: i think you can't send any images without saving atleast you save it temporary folder or hidden folder for security purpose

Comment: @kathayatnk my concern is that the image is saved in temporary location, is it possible that the user can get the picture if he put the app is on background or if the app crash?

Comment: If that's the case you can handle it yourself. You should be able to clean the temp directory easily. Just cleanup after the image is captured

Comment: @kathayatnk If i clean that temp dir after capturing the image and before the user send it via email, doesnt that delete the image and prevent me from using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i just made for you, try the part of the the temp file, i put at the end to me knowledge who do it. Regards

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import MessageUI

class PictureViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func editImage()
    {
        let alerta = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        var accionCamera = UIAlertAction()
        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
        {
            accionCamera = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a picture", style: .default, handler: { (ACTION) in
                self.pickMediaFromSource(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)
            })
            alerta.addAction(accionCamera)
        }

        let accionNo = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alerta.addAction(accionNo)
        present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func pickMediaFromSource(_ sourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)
    {
        let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: sourceType)!
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) && mediaTypes.count > 0
        {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = sourceType

            present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message: "Media not supported", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        let lastChosenMediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String
        if let mediaType = lastChosenMediaType
        {
            if mediaType == kUTTypeImage as String
            {
                let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
                picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.sendEmailFront(image: image!)
                }

                let tmpDirectory = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())

            }
            else if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie  as String
            {
                picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message: "Medio no soportado. Debe ser una imagen", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(okAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                })
                return

            }
        }
    }


    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

    // MARK: - SEND EMAIL
    func sendEmailFront(image: UIImage)
    {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
        {
            let dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["example@gmail.com"])
            mail.addAttachmentData(dataImage!, mimeType: "THE MIME TYPE", fileName: "THE FILE NAME")

            self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true) {

    // TO CHECK IF EXIST ANY FILE TO DELETE, I DON'T FIND ANYTHING BUT, TRY YOU ANYWAY
            let tmpDirectory = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())

            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            let contents = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: urls!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsPackageDescendants)
            print(contents)

        }
    }


}
```